# How do I launch the fish shell in WSL through Cmder?

Tags: terminal, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fish, cmder

Setting it as the default shell in Ubuntu WSL results in the PATH not working properly, as described in the [docs](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#default-shell). So I want to avoid that issue by launching it through the terminal.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Using a non-traditional shell like Fish (or Elvish) as your login shell means that initialization done by files like *~/.bashrc* or */etc/bash.bashrc* won't be done. You also need to be more specific than "PATH not working properly". What was the value of `PATH` and what value did you expect? Too, "launching it through the terminal" also doesn't make much sense. Too, WSL is just a Linux environment and is probably not relevant to your question unless "cmder" (which I've never used) has support for bash that isn't available for a non-bash shell.

Comment: WSL is unrelated to Cmder.

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  To follow up on what @KurtisRader said, if you edit your question to show (a) what you are expecting and (b) what it actually happening, that should hopefully allow us to help you.  *"PATH not working properly"* is definitely far too vague here.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Found out the answer

```
cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe ~ -new_console:p:%USERPROFILE%  /usr/bin/fish
```

as a task